# CADisplayLink firing precision

Tags: ios, opengl-es

- CADisplayLink on main run loop, default mode
- Timing successive invocations using mach_absolute_time()
- Target selector is effectively empty function

Measured times between successive invocations range from **14ms-20ms.**

- What does this mean for attempting to synchronize with screen refresh?
- Is the ~3ms inaccuracy in mach_absolute_time()? Or in CADisplayLink scheduling?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's `mach_absolute_time`, but you might try other mechanisms (i.e. I generally use `CFAbsoluteTime`). And I don't think it's `CADisplayLink` either. It's likely other things happening on that main queue (either stuff that you're doing or stuff that the OS itself is doing).

Just for a point of comparison, when I test `CADisplayLink` with `CFAbsoluteTime` on a reasonably fast device, once the system has reached quiescence, the variability is much less than ± 3ms. I'm seeing less than ± 0.1ms on my iPad (admittedly, I'm not using OpenGL). On the simulator, I see greater variability (probably because there are more processes contending for the CPU).

Comment: Ya, I'm issuing OpenGL calls in that callback - but have reduced the calls to clearing & presenting for these tests. Testing on iPhone 6. I'm not doing anything else on the main thread other then input processing.

Comment: Just gutted all the OpenGL calls, and the input processing. Still have +/- 3ms maximum variability. Don't get me wrong - 95% of the calls are right within +/- 0.5ms - but have no idea what's causing the outliers (one as high as 27ms ??). Makes it hard to reason about how to budget CPU usage for game engine - not confident in how much time I have from invocation -> upper bound on when I can submit rendering calls to maintain GPU frame synchronization.

Comment: Dropping 5/100 frames isn't so good - especially when missing a frame can cause cascading effects with vsync.

Comment: Note, just because 95 are ± 0.5 ms doesn't necessarily mean that you're dropping 5% of frames. I bet your fps isn't that bad.  And even if it is, it puts you in the range of 54 fps, which is solid and is likely visually indistinguishable from 60 fps. But, perhaps you can share [simplified, reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and details about the device that you're testing on. Btw, I assume you're testing optimized release build and not debug build.

Comment: You often can use system calls and time profiler in Instruments to identify the source of delays, though it can be a fairly excruciating process. There are a number of WWDC videos that illustrate the process. (I'm not at a computer right now so I don't have the references in front of me, but there are a couple of applicable videos, with "responsive" in the title, IIRC.)